# When someone says something in a foolish, excited, or incomprehensible way for a brief moment

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes when someone blurts out something quickly and excitedly and in a sort of foolish way? For example, the word babble describes the act of "talking rapidly and continuously in a foolish, excited, or incomprehensible way." The word I'm looking for is similar, but doing it hastily and only for a short bit.

For example, the context I'm using it in is a soldier saying a quick, incomprehensible prayer before the eve of battle that no one around him really catches the meaning of. I could say that he "babbles a prayer," but if he only does it for a short moment, it doesn't really fit the context.

Comment: When someone says something in a foolish, excited, or incomprehensible way for a brief moment, somebody within earshot asks about it on ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "[jibber-jabber](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jibber-jabber)," or simply "jabber."

> **jabber**: to talk in a fast, unclear, or foolish way.

[He jabbered a prayer for mercy and was as humble as Uriah Heep.](http://www.newspapers.com/newspage/54464743/)

[He kneeled down on the kitchen floor, folded his arms and bowed his head, jibber jabbered a prayer, and then said "Amen."](http://letterstoutah.com/?m=201001&paged=2)

Comment: I feel like this works for what I want, especially since the examples are almost spot-on for the usage I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for **mutter**.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutter) says

> **1**
>   :  to utter sounds or words indistinctly or with a low voice and with the lips partly closed
>
> **2**
>   :  to murmur complainingly or angrily :  grumble
>
> ...
>
> transitive verb
>   :  to utter especially in a low or imperfectly articulated manner

Comment: I wanted this at first, but its more like he's blabbing something out emotionally and uncontrollably, not softly and indistinctly.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like "incoherent" would be useful - "He blurted incoherently".

Answer (score 1):

A  *foolish, excited, or incomprehensible way for a brief moment* is a **boutade** or a [sudden outburst or outbreak](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/boutade).

By its nature, all uncontrolled speech is "foolish, excited, or incomprehensible":

**Drivel**: Driv"el, n. 1. Slaver; saliva flowing from the mouth. [1913 Webster]

1. Inarticulate or unmeaning utterance; foolish talk; babble. [1913 Webster]
   -http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/cide/54369/Drivel

**Prate**: v. i. [imp. & p. p. {Prated}; p. pr. & vb. n. {Prating}.] [Akin to LG. & D. praten, Dan. prate, Sw. & Icel. prata.] To talk much and to little purpose; to be loquacious; to speak foolishly; to babble. [1913 Webster]

To prate and talk for life and honor. --Shak. [1913 Webster] -http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/cide/137596/Prate

**Inaniloquent**: [prone to foolish or empty babbling](http://phrontistery.enacademic.com/2229/inaniloquent)

**Footle**:      [intransitive verb (footled; footling) Etymology: probably alteration of footer to waste time Date: 1892 1. to talk or act foolishly 2. to waste time ; trifle, fool • footle noun • footler noun](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mwc/23304/footle)

If you are mad as hell, an **ebullition** [1 :  a sudden violent outburst or display
2 :  the act, process, or state of boiling or bubbling up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ebullition) , or a **fantod**:  [an emotional outburst](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fantod) fit  suits your "brief moment" limitation

Comment: Oooh, very nice! Thank you for the well-researched answers! These are all very eloquent, but I need a verb rather than a noun. Footle is nice, but not quite what I needed. I will have to remember fantod for later!

Answer (score 0):

*Gabbler* would be correct to say.

Comment: Interesting, is this a noun then? As in, one who gabbles?